# I want to install Ubuntu MATE as a single OS over Windows 7. Can anyone help how?

Tags: software-installation, windows

I want to install Ubuntu Mate on my laptop which already has Windows 7. I want to ask how do I install Ubuntu so that Data of my other Hard Drive partitions like D:\, E:\ remain safe? I really want to switch to Linux environment. Can anybody help?

Comment: You cant install an OS with out erasing the previous one along with it files, however, you may be able to keep the `D:\` drive, i'm no expert, but you can find out how to install Ubuntu here : http://askubuntu.com/questions/221835/installing-ubuntu-on-a-pre-installed-windows-with-uefi, same goes for Ubuntu MATE.